# Read delimited section of text file into variable in CMD

Tags: xml, batch-file, cmd

Using a CMD batch file, I want a simple way to read the contents of the label **pano_id** from this XML file into a variable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><panorama><data_properties image_width="13312" image_height="6656" tile_width="512" tile_height="512" image_date="2015-05" pano_id="_1OPn-SzCb5SkjEENmq7Pg" scene="1" imagery_type="5" level_id="5d4d985b8a990000" num_zoom_levels="5" lat="29.813101" lng="34.942808" original_lat="29.813101" original_lng="34.942808" elevation_wgs84_m="645.826720" elevation_egm96_m="629.255798"><copyright>© 2017 Google</copyright><text>Israel National Trail: Timna Lake to Be’er Metek</text><country>Israel</country></data_properties><projection_properties projection_type="spherical" pano_yaw_deg="124.649994" tilt_yaw_deg="-67.56" tilt_pitch_deg="6.0899997"/><annotation_properties><link yaw_deg="303.69" pano_id="_PGTJI1Vr6P4lSTHuegprQ" road_argb="0x80fdf872"><link_text></link_text></link><link yaw_deg="121.09" pano_id="Ip1M1lvUUebjfR0WEEbM0g" road_argb="0x80fdf872"><link_text></link_text></link></annotation_properties></panorama>
```

For example, the variable %panorama% would be set to **_1OPn-SzCb5SkjEENmq7Pg**.

How can I do this?  Thanks.

Comment: I strongly recommend switching to PowerShell for this sort of thing... PowerShell works natively with XML.

Comment: Or Vbscript or Jscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with [**xpath.bat**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/xpath.bat) - it can extract values from xml by xpath expressions using only windows build-in capabilities:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('xpath.bat "xml.xml" "//data_properties/@pano_id"') do ( 
  set "panorama=%%~#"
)
echo %panorama%
```

You should be sure the xml encoding is really `utf-8` otherwise the parsing will fail.